# can a bounded ratio of two polynomials have unbounded derivative?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

Let $P(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ and $Q(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ be two polynomials and assume that $$f(x_1,\cdots,x_m)=\frac{Q(x_1,\cdots,x_m)}{P(x_1,\cdots,x_m)}$$ is bounded over some region $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.
Can $f$ have an unbounded derivative over $D$? By unbounded I mean that $|\nabla f|\rightarrow \infty$ somewhere in $D$.

Comment: By assumption, $P$ is never zero on $D$, hence $f$ is a smooth function...

Comment: Can you do the case $n=1$?

Comment: @GiulioR But it’s not by assumption, it could be that the roots of $P$ in $D$ are also roots of $Q$ , right?

Comment: You can assume that P doesnt have any roots in $D$ (because you can rewrite the equation as $P'/Q'$ where P' and Q' dont have any root in common. Like the preceding comments pointed, it follows naturally from this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl; dr: Yes. (!!)

---

In Cartesian plane coordinates $(x, y)$, let
$$
P(x, y) = y,\qquad
Q(x, y) = x.
$$
Formally,
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{y}{x},\qquad
\nabla f(x, y) = \biggl(-\frac{y}{x^{2}}, \frac{1}{x}\biggr).
$$
Particularly, $|y|/x^{2} < |\nabla f(x, y)|$. It remains only to find a region where $y/x$ is bounded and $|y|/x^{2}$ is not, such as
$$
D = \{(x, y) : 0 < y < |x|^{3/2}\}.
$$

Comment: Thats right. What if I say that every root of $P$ is also a root of $Q$?

Comment: I was definitely wrong :) (+1)

Comment: @user3350919 Over the reals, an example such as $P(x, y) = x^2+y^2$, $Q(x, y) = y^3$ has the same qualitative behavior. (If you're working over the complex numbers, that's another matter.)

Comment: @GiulioR I was a little surprised myself (hence the exclamation marks). :)